# Shortest Manhattan distance from point to line

Tags: geometry

Given a point $(x_{01},x_{02},...,x_{0n})$ in n-dimensional space and a line $(x_{l1}(t),x_{l2}(t),...,x_{ln}(t))$, does the shortest taxicab path from the point to the line intersect the line at the same place as the shortest Euclidean path from the point to the line?

Comment: the shortest taxicab path is not unique: consider y=x and (-1,1) on the plane.

Comment: Think about the shape of the unit sphere in the Manhattan metric in two dimensions;

Comment: Good point @Daniele: (0,0), (-1,-1), and (1,1) intersection points on y=x are all shortest paths with different points of intersection.

Comment: Can you clarify that when you write "shortest taxicab path" you mean "shortest path under the taxicab metric" and likewise for "shortest Euclidean path"? My reason for asking is that "taxicab path" suggests a path that is piecewise linear with all segments parallel to one of the axes, but I think you are interested in the shortest path of any kind under the appropriate metric.

Comment: "**Shortest** Manhattan distance" is redundant. "Distance" is already defined as the **minimum** length of a path.

Answer (score 2):

In general, there will be a unique shortest path, the exception being when the line makes $45°$ angles with the "streets" as described in the comments. But indeed, it will not generally be the Euclidean path. Instead, you should move parallel to an appropriate set of streets, no matter what angle you make with the line.

For example, if the streets are given by constant $x$ coordinates and constant $y$ coordinates, and you want the shortest distance from the origin to $2x+y=2$, you should properly move along the $x$-axis (a constant-$y$ street) to $(1,0)$. The shortest path with the Euclidean norm would intersect instead at $(4/5,2/5)$.

Comment: Your are promulgating the OP's very confusing terminology by writing "shortest Euclidean path" when you mean "shortest path under the Euclidean metric".

Comment: OK: no offence intended about your language skills. I will comment on the original post.

Comment: So who downvotes this? Probably not the one who actually suggested an improvement. It always seems that way.

Comment: I certainly didn''t downvote and hope we get to a good solution of the question.

Comment: I know. I'm ragging on whoever did.

Comment: I am checking this answer, does the shortest path under the Euclidean metric intersect at $(4/5,2/5)$? If this is right, I will edit the answer and accept it. If I am wrong, please explain, and I will accept the answer. Also, I am not sure how to change the language of the question. I wanted to find the path along segments parallel to the axes vs the straight path. Will someone help me edit the question?